# how does Spring decide the order of initializing Bean and plain class?

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean as below，

```
 @Component 
 public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware { 

     private static ApplicationContext context = null; 

     @Override 
     public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) 
         throws BeansException { 
     this.context = applicationContext; 
     } 

     public static <T> T getBean(String beanName) { 
         return (T) context.getBean(beanName); 
     } 

     public static String getActiveProfile() { 
         return context.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles()[0]; 
     } 
 }
```

it is used by a plain class,

```
public class ConfigUtil
{
    static{
        String env = SpringContextUtil.getActiveProfile();
        ...
    }

    public static getVal(String key){...}
}
```

If the Spring Bean SpringContextUtil is initialized after the plain class ConfigUtil, then it is not OK. 
So I want to know how Spring decide which one is initilialized earlier? For example, will the invocation of SpringContextUtil.getActiveProfile() trigger the initialization of the Spring bean? or the Spring Bean is only initialized but havn't been injected applicationContext yet, thus leads to a Null Pointer Exeception?

Comment: See, you yourself know that "it is not OK". So why are you keep doing this?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html

Comment: @Datz, unlikely. Here he has a non-Spring class that depends on Spring to be fully-loaded when the class is loaded. No amount of Spring configuration can help there, I'm pretty sure, as this happens outside of its control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to run your code after spring has been initialized.

If you're using spring-boot, create new bean that implements [`ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationReadyEvent.html) and run your code inside the `onApplicationEvent` method.

**Example**

```
@Component
public class ApplicationListenerBean implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {
        ConfigUtil.getVal("A");
    }
}
```

However if you want to make `ConfigUtil` also as a spring bean you need to get rid of static initialization block and use instead [`@PostConstruct`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) annotation on your init method.

**Example**

```
@Component
@DependsOn("springContextUtil")
public class ConfigUtil {

    private String env;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        env = SpringContextUtil.getActiveProfile();
    }


    public static void getVal(String key) {
        System.out.print("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's the @DependsOn("springContextUtil") that works. if remove this, NullPointerException  may still happen. Because the inited order of bean ConfigUtil and SpringContextUtil is not guaranteed, also static call won't cause bean SpringContextUtil inited. so context may be null